# Send email to particular store customer in multi store website in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, email, multistore, multi-website

Guy's I have a multi-store website in Magento 2.2.5, in one admin side manage 7 to 8 store, so I have to install  Trustpilot review extention in one store.

But when I send customer invitation mail to send mail whole website all customers.

So how can I send mail particular store customers?

Please give suggestions for that otherwise any condition for that so send mail only this store customer.